# Using STDIN to input a list and output a sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

I am trying to create a function that will return a sublist of numbers in a range (start to finish) from a list using STDIN.

However, I am running to a couple of problems and I can't seem to tackle them as I need to use a list of integers. This is the code I am trying to implement.

```
import sys

def algo(list1, xs, xf):
    for x in list1:
      if x>=xs or x<=xf:
      print(x)

list1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" ")
xs = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" ")
xf = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" ")

algo(list1, xs, xf)
```

Using this approach and using input 1 2 3 40 50 90 100 with start being 3 and finish being 100 I get

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'
```

If I make all of the stdins an int() as in

```
list1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" ")
xs = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" "))
xf = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip().split(" "))
```

I still get

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

So I can not convert a list into an int. However I need to use stdin for my application. How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: What were you hoping to achieve by checking if some string `x` in `list1` is `>=` or `<=` to some other list as a whole?

Comment: What I am trying to implement with xs and xf is just a single number, I dont want to be making it a list. Lets say 3 for xs and 40 for xf. So if my list was 10 20 30 41, my algorithm should return 10 20 30.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple example to get you started.  It might need some adjustments. See below:

```
lastValue = -1
for x in list1:
  for y in xs:
    for z in xf:
      if x != lastValue and (x >= y or x <= z):       
        print(x)
        lastValue = x
```

Your problem is that you're not iterating over your lists `xs` or `xf` at all.  A nested loop should do the trick, otherwise you won't be able to compare every value in `list1` to every value in `xs` or `xf`.

I'm using the `lastValue` variable to avoid printing any duplicates.  This example assumes all my lists contain integers, you may need to cast `x`, `y`, and `z` to `int` to work with your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Something I want to point out is that xs and xf are just a value. I do not want them to be a list.

For example. Let's say I am not using stdin.

    list1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70, 81]
    xs = 40
    xf = 80
   print(algo(list1, xs, xf)) will give me an output of 40, 60, 70. This is what I am trying to implement but with using stdin.

Comment: While that may be what you want, the way you're calling `stdin.readline()` produces a list of strings separated by spaces from a single line in a file.  Refer to [this link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).  So if you want to isolate a specific value from the line you're reading in then you will need to do something like the above (unless you change how you're creating `xs` and `xf`).